How to apply a function to each row of a panel data set
I am trying to calculate measurements of Gini Coefficients using Gini() function in R for each state from a panel data set. I have observations for each of the 50 US states over 14 years - appx 714 rows.
using packages "plm" , "DescTools"
For each observation (row), I have 4 values that I am trying to calculate the Gini coefficient from. If I manually make each row into a list - e.g.
> ginis.01 <- c(80.4, 79.8, 80.1, 82.3)
> Gini(ginis.01)
[1] 0.008059516

It functions fine. However I need to do this for every row, and then average the coefficient by each state.
To define a new column in the dataframe I've tried
> DataTable5$gini <- Gini(DataTable5$le_agg_q1_F, DataTable5$le_agg_q2_F, DataTable5$le_agg_q3_F, DataTable5$le_agg_q4_F)

But it returns the error
Error in if (is.na(conf.level)) { : the condition has length > 1

Ultimately, I would like to average this calculated gini for each state-year observation with the years for each state to get a single coefficient for each state.
Earlier, I tried specifying individual rows by doing
AL2001obs <- c(DataTable5$le_raceadj_q1_F[1], DataTable5$le_raceadj_q2_F[1], DataTable5$le_raceadj_q3_F[1], DataTable5$le_raceadj_q4_F[1])`

ALgini2001 <- Gini(AL2001obs)

ALgini2001
[1] 0.01244335 

AL.ginis <- c(ALgini2001, ALgini2002, ALgini2003, ...)
AL.avg.gini <- mean(AL.ginis)

but this has resulted in a lot of errors on my part with all the tedious copy / paste / editing.
In short, I am trying to take 4 values from each row and apply the Gini function to them (to see how unequal they are by this metric in a given year), then take the mean() of those Gini coefficients for all 14 years for each given state and have that average value appear in the data frame for each state (same average state value every 14 rows since there are 14 observations per state).
new column should say "average gini" and show one avg value for each state in the set.
Hopefully this is clear, I am relatively new to R and programming in general. Thank you

A similar question has been asked here before, which may help your situation. In the future, please include a small sample of your data using dput() (or dput(head()) to show just a few rows) to make it easier for other users to answer your question.

Try mapply(Gini, DataTable5$le_agg_q1_F, DataTable5$le_agg_q2_F, DataTable5$le_agg_q3_F, DataTable5$le_agg_q4_F)
